# Rails 3 How can I allow nested attributes to be passed without the _attributes designation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

When using accepts_nested_attributes_for, instead of having to pass "child_attributes", I'd like to pass "child".  I'm pretty sure if I put a lot of the logic in my controller to create the the records and children, I could accomplish this.  However, in an effort to keep my controllers clean and logic where it should be, the model in this case, I'd like to know how to switch rails 3 around to use this syntax when doing a POST or PUT.

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "child_attributes": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "test_child_update"
    },
    {
      "name": "test_child_create"
    }
}
```

Rather

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "child": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "test_child_update"
    },
    {
      "name": "test_child_create"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask why you want to change this?

Comment: There is a reason for this convention, as the `child` attribute actually refers to the collection of `Child` objects, not the attributes of the `Child` objects.  The `child_attributes` attribute is used to clarify intent.

Comment: I'm going to wade in here. The type of the object being passed in should be enough to determine the intent. Also, since there are no classes in JSON, using `_attributes` does not actually clear anything up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evidently, this can't be done.

Comment: I think you are the only one on Stack that admits something can't be done

Answer (score 2):

The `_attributes` suffix adds no value to JSON requests and responses, but to get rid of it in the model layer, you would have to monkey patch ActiveRecord. Everyone hates monkey-patching ActiveRecord relations.

How about doing it in the controller layer?

```
@comment = Comment.new(attributify(:comment))

# snip

# ApplicationController

def attributify()
  # Now I'll go and write this!
end
```

Edit: Done. The controller mixin is here: https://gist.github.com/johncant/6056036